# Why Microsoft invented KQL rather than using SQL for Azure Data Explorer

Tags: kql

`Azure Data Explorer` uses `Kusto Query Language (KQL)`. Why `Microsoft` didn't use `SQL` ?

```
LogEvents
| where StartTime > datetime(2021-12-31) 
| where EventType == 'Error'
| project StartTime, EventType , Message
```

The same could be written in `sql` saving developers effort to learn a new language

`select StartTime, EventType, Message from LogEvents where  startime >  ....`

Comment: Please share more details. How is this problem related to programming?

Comment: This is an interesting question. Well done whoever closed it, big pat on the back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And from another perspective -

Why KQL (and not just SQL)?

- The SQL query structure holds in some bad design decisions.
  Starting a query with a SELECT clause (and not FROM clause) harms the natural flow of query writing and the chances for a decent IntelliSense.
  The relation between the GROUP BY clause and the SELECT clause (which contains the aggregate functions) has a similar effect.
- SQL result dataset schema is always known in advance.
  While useful from multiple perspective, it is also very limiting. Consider plugins like *pivot* or *bag_unpack* (without an output schema).
- SQL has a rigid structure that requires a cumbersome nesting.
  Consider aggregation over aggregation or filtering on a windows function (Teradata has the *Qualify* operator for many years and it was recently also adopted by Spark, however it is not part of the SQL standard).
- SQL expressions aliasing is very limited (with Teradata as an exception), leading to cumbersome queries nesting / code duplications which harms readability and prone to errors.
- SQL has various filtering clause (WHERE / HAVING / QUALIFY) for different scenarios, which is quite confusing for users.
- SQL is standardized only on its basics.
  Different RDBMS / SQL engines use different data types, functions, hints, non-standard clauses etc. Sometimes the exact same syntax, lead to different results (consider a windows function with order by clause or even something allegedly trivial as a substring function that gets a negative value as a start position).
  If different SQL engines are so different from each other, why being bound by SQL at all?
- SQL development (as a standard) seems to be stuck.
  It is somewhere between painfully slow and non-existent.
  There is a massive progress done by Spark SQL, but this is an initiative around a single SQL engine, detached from the SQL standard.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, while KQL is the preferred language by Azure Data Explorer, it does support basic SQL.
See [T-SQL support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/tds/t-sql).
Please note the intention here is for SQL in the T-SQL dialect and not for the T-SQL procedural language.

```
--
with LogEvents as (select now() as StartTime, 'Error' as EventType, 'Hello World' as Message)
select StartTime, EventType , Message
from LogEvents
where StartTime > cast('2021-12-31' as date) and EventType = 'Error'
```

| StartTime | EventType | Message |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-29T17:16:43.414266Z | Error | Hello World |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA02OMQuDMBCFdyH/4TYVDDTp3G5Ch3aq0DmYqwrRlMtR6b%20vCbW6vnffu09Kkc0D93D1Xf3GiQOYAEVAhy3D5OeijMGdDXEzjFhBXhN5ymOagObziukFnfPw8ORs6m4YgumwFNlvazfx56Ba70T2JD9uFotVj4QbBWdoTeAi1wetpNLyqNIfaxgXxcnuVk%20r5Bduzmf33gAAAA==)